# Android.mk seems to ignore LOCAL_C_INCLUDES and can't find GLES2 includes

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I'm currently trying to get the sample project from the FastCV API from Qualcomm to run. Since eclipse couldn't find any of the required includes, I tried adding the path to the Android.mk. I read the provided docs about it, and one could add simply the path to the includes via the LOCAL_C_INCLUDES. But the NDK seems to ignore the path, and still complains about missing includes. When I add the same path to the "Include directory"-list via the project properties, it works fine beside eclipse still won't find the GLES2 files.

The sample needs this includes:

```
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fastcv/fastcv.h>
```

And the Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=  vendor/qcom-proprietary/blur/tests/fastcvsample/jni \
                     vendor/qcom-proprietary/blur/lib/fastcv/inc \
                     platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
```

This doesn't work. If I add *C:\android-ndk-r6\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include* to the includes via eclipse it will find all files except the two GLES2 ones (but they are definitely in that directory). Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

nkd-build reports this:

```
C:/fastcv-android-1-0-2/samples/fastcorner/jni/FastCVSample.cpp:14:23: error: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or directory
C:/fastcv-android-1-0-2/samples/fastcorner/jni/FastCVSample.cpp:15:26: error: GLES2/gl2ext.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try putting it in Application.mk as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. You need to read the [install instructions](https://developer.qualcomm.com/develop/mobile-technologies/computer-vision-fastcv/compiling-and-running-fastcv-sample-app) very closely, there are mentioned several libraries that need to be copied. You also have to watch to which API directory you copy it. Since the sample is geared towards API level 8, you need to copy it into the andriod-8 folder, not -9 or whatever you use else. The entries in the mk files don't seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason ndk-build searches for the required library in the lower API versions, but when it finds fastcv, it will not find GLES2. Make sure you copy the fastcv libs only to the versions that have GLES2 defined.